# Can DC/OS run in Offline Mode

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

Can DC/OS run on in an offline environment? 
After a successfull installation in my offline environemnt the login web screen would not open with the following message:
 
`The server refused the connection`.

Comment: Need more details. What do you mean by offline mode. DC/OS Vagrant?

Comment: Hi Ofir ben

  Can you give us procedure how to install dcos in offline mode. I've requriement like need to install dcos in machines which does not have intenet conenction, it has intranet connection. 
Can you explain whta is "my offline environment" i.e how is your environment? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Michael, Any help? . Please ask if you don't have clear with my question. thank in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable authentication in my cluster because Im running it in a private offline network. 

Just add the following line  in `genconf/config.yaml` before custom installation: 

`oatuh_enabled: 'false'`

this way authentication needed.

https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/opt-out/